# Which HTML tags are indispensable for a HTML document?

Tags: html

Forget about those smart rendering engines of state-of-art browsers. In terms of the W3C standards, which are the "indispensable" (non-removable) tags for a standard HTML document?

Furthermore, is there any difference about it in the HTML5 standard?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your motivation for asking this question?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Just curiosity. and I failed to find answers in my textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the validator](http://validator.w3.org/check), this is valid:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
```

**edit:** Even smaller:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Title</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements which every document must have are: `<html>`, `<head>`, `<title>`.

Comment: ...and no less than 3 `<marquee>`s (2 if you wrap them in `<blink>`).

Comment: The `<body>` tag appears to be optional, actually. `<html>` too, if the validator is to be believed.

Comment: @srini.venigalla: But it's not valid according to the specs.

Comment: The `<body>` *element* is mandatory too. But the *tags* are not. Which is the same as `<html>` and `<head>`. Only the `<title>` *tags* are required, as @ceejayoz correctly answers.

Answer (score 0):

By the HTML 4.01 specification, the only obligatory tags are `<title>` and `</title>`. The same goes for the HTML5 drafts. In XHTML, different rules apply, see the spec.